# Comment flags are anonymous

Tags: discussion, comment, flagging

Just in case you are not aware: to help prevent abuse by moderators, the system is designed so that [certain flags are **anonymous**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15947/is-my-flagging-data-history-anonymous-to-volunteer-elected-moderators). In particular, with the current flagging system (rumour has it that SE is preparing an upgrade in the near future),

- Spam/Offensive flags on posts are anonymous.
- Comment flags are anonymous.

That is to say, if you actually *want* a moderator to respond to *you*, you should *not* raise a custom *comment* flag asking a question: we wouldn't know to whom to address the response. If you have some concerns about moderation and would like to receive a response, please place the flag on a question, or on an answer, instead, and use the free-form text entry field there.

(Other options include: go into chat and ping one of the mods who are there more frequently [say, robjohn]. For moderation issues we are allowed to open up a private chatroom to discuss the problem with you. Or you can [send one of us an e-mail](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6820/announcement-private-contacts-by-moderators) [though the response may come through some other means].)

---

If you read the above and think that I may be in fact talking about something you did recently... yes, that's right. Please follow the above advice so the moderators would know to whom to address our answer!

Comment: Good to know. I guess this also ties in with the lower character limit on comment flags?

Comment: @Lord_Farin: I am not sure if it "ties in". But certainly the lower character limit of comment flags makes it more attractive to use question/answer flags for longer queries to the moderators.

Comment: What about 'this is not an answer' flags?

Comment: @GitGud: my list above is exhaustive.